# How to create an empty google map with only street names

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am working on a `Geolocation` application in which I want to populate a Google map with my own (local) data. But there are a lot of objects on the map already, plus my own markers makes it so busy and confusing for user. I wonder how I can start with an almost empty map with only names of places. I have searched for that but I can't find any configuration on google map which makes it empty. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) to control which kinds of features are displayed on a map you build with the [JavaScript Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Start by experimenting with the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) until you get the effect you want, then use the Show JSON button to get the data object you can use with the Styled Maps API.

For example, I used the Wizard to turn off *all* features and then turn on only Roads/Labels. This was the resulting data:

```
[
  {
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can copy that into code like this [simple styled map example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple).

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geary/c3zupt25/2/) with the above styles so you can experiment further.

Answer (score 2):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'))
```

Can be found on the [tutorial page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Comment: tanks for your reply , but i couldn't find any option regarding my question on that link.could you please provide a fiddle?or at least give me a point on that page which partition exactly refers to answer.

Comment: Scroll down to "Hello, world"..... The code is here, that's the simplest code, the most basic stuff to initialize a Google map.

Comment: +1 for the answer.but Michael's answer is more complete.i will mark that one as wnswer.but nevertheless thanks for you'r time.

Comment: No problem :) You said, "I want an empty map" and that's exactly what it does.

Comment: but it is not empty!really i still can see a lot of icons on it.but if you provide a fiddle with empty map i will mark you as answer (just because you answered earlier).

Comment: Okay here's one : http://jsfiddle.net/vk4d8zrw/1/ You mean you don't even want the road labels like [A32]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79632/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-jeremy-thille).